# Xcode not replacing Core Data managed objects

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

In Xcode when I chose "Create NSManagedObject Subclass..." and selected "Replace" when "The following files already exist and will be replaced:" prompted, Xcode did not replace those managed objects files at all.  I always ended up manually deleting those files before trying to create the managed objects files again.

Any suggestions what I have missed?

Comment: It is definitely a bug in Xcode 6.2.

Comment: Moreover, to make code sense correctly notice the changes in this files you have to 'touch' some higher-level header or prefix file where headers of this subclasses are imported.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning the Build?

Product-> clean

Comment: I have been doing that.  No effect though.